# What is a "7-9" chord? (G7-9, etc..)

Tags: theory, chords, notation

There's a chord in the Lennie Niehaus arrangement of the Stan Kenton Orchestra version of Laura, written by Johnny Mercer and David Raksin.

This chord is written as G<sup>7-9</sup>.

In googling, I get G<sup>7(#9)</sup> a lot, but I'm not sure if that's the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be a G7b9 chord. Where the 9th is flattened from A to Ab. So, the whole chord has pitches **G B D F Ab**

Although the "-" sign is sometimes used to denote a minor chord (a chord with a minor 3rd), it can also be used to denote a minor, flattened or diminished interval in a chord. For example -5 for b5, or in this case -9 for b9.

Comment: *Laura* is one of my favourite tunes ever, BTW...!

Comment: It's beautiful! I've got one of the solos in it (trombone) and it's probably the best excuse I've ever had to get more acquainted with some of these jazz chords. Thanks so much! I'll accept as soon as the timer allows me to.

Comment: @BobBroadley - totally with you on Laura. It's well in my repertoire.  One of those rare tunes where the melody is (sometimes) not reflected in the chord notes. And, 7-9 = o, to sum it up, nearly!!